# Converting cURL statement to HTTR

Tags: r, httr

I have a statement written in cURL that looks something like this:

```
curl --request POST \
     --url https://api.secure.com/v1/Test \
     --header 'Accept: application/json' \
     --header 'Authorization: Basic 123456789==' \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --data '{"playerId":12827}'
```

I know how to part of it, which would look something like this:

```
POST(
  'https://api.secure.com/v1/Test',
  accept_json(),
  add_headers(Accept = 'application/json',
              Authorization = APIKey)
)
```

But where I get lost and I'm having trouble finding in the httr package documentation is what to do about the data flag (`--data '{"playerId":12827}`)

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried adding the parameter `body = list(playerId = 12827)`  to the `POST` call?

Comment: Where would I add that?

Comment: As an argument to `POST`, say just before the last curly bracket

Comment: ??? 

There are no curly brackets in my post above

Comment: Sorry, I meant parenthesis

Comment: Try `POST('https://api.secure.com/v1/Test', accept_json(), add_headers(Accept = 'application/json', Authorization = APIKey), body = list(playerId = 12827))`

Comment: I'm given this response: `"errors": [
    {
      "code": "UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE",
      "text": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource."
    }
  ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually send the data and set the correct content type. You can do this with `content_type_json()` and the `body=` parameter (pass your data as a list and POST will turn that into JSON for you).

```
APIKey <- "123456789=="
POST(
  'https://api.secure.com/v1/Test',     # --url https://api.secure.com/v1/Test \
  accept_json(),                        # --header 'Accept: application/json'
  content_type_json(),                  # --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
  add_headers(Authorization = APIKey),  # --header 'Authorization: Basic 123456789=='
  encode = "json",
  body=list(playerId = 12827)           # --data '{"playerId":12827}'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I just tried running it and got this response:

`Response [https://api.secure.com/v1/Test]
  Date: 2021-08-17 17:02
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 144 B
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "INVALID_PARAMETER",
      "text": "The body of the request is null or cannot be parsed."
    }
  ]`

Comment: Try also adding `encode ="json"` as above. It's hard to tell without seeing any documentation for the API endpoint.